# How do I implement a segmented Text box in c# that enforces user to enter values in specific format?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to implement a text box in windows forms where users must follow the constraint of the format of the values. For example, I want to force them to enter numbers in format: 00-000-0-0000, and I want the dashes to be present in the text box. I thought these are called segmented or formatted text input, but found nothing in google about it. Any sort of hint is appreciated.

Comment: MaskedTextBox comes to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for MaskedTextBox which is exactly designed for such cases, you can find more info about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

For your sample you just need to set the Mask property of MaskedTextBox to the format you provided:

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00-000-0-0000";
```